# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' email' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I try to update a data from database, and the result is error 
this full error

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column
>   not found: 1054 Unknown column ' email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select
>   count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = Annisa@gmail.com
>   and `id` <> 10)

controller

```
public function update(Requests\UserUpdateRequest  $request, $id)
{
     $admin = User::where('id', $id)->first();
     $admin->name = $request->name;
     $admin->email = $request->email;
     $admin->save();

     return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with('message', 'Data Admin berhasil diubah!');
 }
```

file request

```
class UserUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'name' => 'required', 
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users, email,' . $this->route("admin"),
            'password' => 'required_with:password_confirmation|confirmed'
        ];
    }
}
```

anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Remove the space before email `unique:users, email,'` should be `unique:users,email,'`

Comment: wow great thanks for help